# Android Simple Menu Errors

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I am trying to create a simple Android Options menu inside a fragment with three different options. I'm getting an error on onCreate that says "savedInstanceState cannot be resolved to a variable." an error on the setContentView that says: "The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type Settings." An error that says "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Settings, String, int). I have seen a couple tutorials that did the menu the same way I am using...can someone help?

Here is the Fragment class:

```
 package com.mapping.application;

 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.Toast;



public class Settings extends Fragment{

 Button button;
 ImageView image;
 private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;


public Settings() {
//    mCallback = null;
}

public static Settings newInstance() {
    return new Settings();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedIstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.item1:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Option1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.item2:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Option2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.item3:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Option3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;


    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the calling activity for this fragment?

Comment: Well, in your `onCreate` method you spelled the variable savedIstanceState instead of savedI`n`stanceState

Comment: You've obviously taken your code from a tutorial which uses an `Activity` instead of a `Fragment`. The method `setContentView` doesn't apply to a `Fragment` - you need to use `onCreateView` instead. The `makeText(Context, CharSequence, int)` method is obviously expecting a `Context` as the first parameter and a `Fragment` isn't a `Context`. In your call to `makeText` use `getActivity()` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Settings extends Fragment{

 Button button;
 ImageView image;
 private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;


public Settings() {
//    mCallback = null;
}

public static Settings newInstance() {
    return new Settings();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //This method is the one you use to add a view to a fragment
    //onCreate doesn't need to be overridden for that
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //This line is important! It tells the Activity that this fragment wants to
    //participate on the creation of the menu
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.item1:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Option1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.item2:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Option2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.item3:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Option3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;


    }
}
```

Comment: That mostly worked. I'm still getting errors in the makeText function. It says "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Settings, String, int)"

Comment: Change it to look like this

`Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Option2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`